# NFC accessory for iPhone (e.g. iCarte 420)

Tags: iphone, ios5, nfc, iphone-accessory

Is anybody aware of the market available NFC reader hardware accessory for the iPhone? This should have Objective-C API (i.e. use of the "External Accessory framework") and should use the dock connector, not Bluetooth.

I am aware of the iCarte 420, but I am not sure if they are delivering small quantities for developers.

Any comments and experience with programming of NFC external HW on iPhone is welcomed.

Regards,
STeN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written apps using the iCarte 420.

You do have to include the external accessory framework, as well as the api provided by WDI (the iCarte manufacturer). It is accessed via the dock, and not through blutooth.

The provided API is extensive, but lacks NDEF, so you must communicate with your tag of choice at the 'block' or sector level with say mifare, or tranceive command for something like Desfire.

Your best bet is to contact the folks at iCarte (WDI) and purchase a development kit. They've been helpful gettingme started.

Be aware that before you can submit your app to the app store, WDI will have to 'whitelist' each app before apple will accept.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing your experiences with the audience. I have already send them a request using emails i have found on their web pages. Regards,STeN

Comment: How much does that developer kit run?

Comment: Hi Anansi - do you have any contact to iCarte sales or representatives? I am trying to call then and send them emails for more then 2 weeks, but nobody is answering. It's very strange - to me it looks like company does not exists anymore...

Comment: WDI are not responding to emails requesting information on the iCarte on any of their three website listed email addresses. I suspect this is a fly-by-night solution until the NFC equipped iPhone 5 is released shortly when the iCarte becomes defunct, so the money has been expended, gullible buyers found, expenses recouped, and the operation wound down and personnel deployed elsewhere. Vaporware, or has anybody actually seen more than a few prototypes in one place? Feel free to let us know otherwise!